# Change H2 compatibility mode attribute only

Tags: database, h2, compatibility, mode

I am using H2 in the (default) REGULAR compatibility mode, but to make it compatible with some DBMS systems that I use simultaneously, I'd like to set **ONLY** the attribute `zeroExLiteralsAreBinaryStrings` ([MODE and its attributes](http://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/engine/Mode.html)).

Is there a way to change it **without** having to set a MODE on the connection string?

I know that changing MODE to MySQL would set this attribute, but on my case it affects other places and system breaks due to other reasons.

What I've tried so far:

- setting the compatibility MODE to some other enums;
  Other enums set other undesired flags
- getting hibernate objects to reach that attribute and set it accordingly;
  I couldn't reach that attribute specifically
- checking the H2 database to change it programmatically;
  SETTINGS table only differs in MODE value. There isn't a `zeroExLiteralsAreBinaryStrings` stored value.
- create a new Mode / extend Mode;
  org.h2.engine.Mode constructor has private access

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work unwrapping the Connection object and reaching inner H2 settings:

```java
// I already had Connection connection
JdbcConnection h2Connection = connection.unwrap(JdbcConnection.class);

h2Connection.getSession().getDynamicSettings().mode.zeroExLiteralsAreBinaryStrings = false;
System.out.println(h2Connection.getSession().getDynamicSettings().mode.zeroExLiteralsAreBinaryStrings);

h2Connection.getSession().getDynamicSettings().mode.zeroExLiteralsAreBinaryStrings = true;
System.out.println(h2Connection.getSession().getDynamicSettings().mode.zeroExLiteralsAreBinaryStrings);
```